# Modifying look/behavior of the new Popup control (ChildWindow) in Silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I would like to remove grey header of the new Popup control in Silverlight 3.

Any ideas if this is possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pretty easy, just edit the default ChildWindow style.

1. In Blend 3 create a new Item of type ChildWindow. (Right Click on the Project --> New Item --> Select ChildWindow from the list)
2. Right click on ChildWindow in the "Objects and Timeline" pane --> Edit Template --> Edit Copy.
3. Navigate to the element named "Chrome" inside the default template and change the Background to whatever Brush you'd like.

Comment: Thanks, I had only found part of the solution by setting Template = null in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Styling is the best way to do it, but you can also remove it by setting Title="" HasCloseButton="False" on your ChildWindow.