# How to hide the header for Silverlight 3 DataForm control

Tags: silverlight-3.0, dataform

I'm using the DataForm control in my SL3 app, it has a header with some icons by default (edit, delete, navigation etc. etc.), I can prevent most of the icons from appearing on the header, but **want to get rid of the header all together**. haven't had much luck with google...

Answer (score 3):

In xaml set the property on the dataform like so:

```
CommandButtonsVisibility="None"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the header of the new popup control in SL3.

[Modifying look/behavior of the new Popup control (ChildWindow) in Silverlight 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684360/modifying-look-behavior-of-the-new-popup-control-childwindow-in-silverlight-3)

Same solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure of Silverlight 3, but in Silverlight 4 it's like this:

```
HeaderVisibility="Collapsed"
```